# all street coordinates with google api

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps API. I wanted to know if is there a way to get a consultation with all the numbers in a street with their respective coordinates of latitude and longitude.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure what you mean by "all street coordinates"  - how can one consulta have multiple street addresses? Can you make a real world example? (Also, Stack Overflow is an English only site, please translate your question. Thanks!)

Comment: You can check out the [Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish) for a Spanish Stack Overflow. It is currently in the commitment phase.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote (courtesy of [translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com)):

> I'm using the Google Maps API. I wanted to know if there is any way to get a consultation with all the numbers in a street with their latitude and longitude coordinates.

Not using the Google Maps API.  You can retrieve individual locations, but Reverse-Geocoding is subject to a quota and a rate limit.  Bulk downloads, scraping the data and using the data on non-Google Maps is against the [terms of use](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos).

Try [openstreetmaps](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)